# Validação Jquery usando array nos input names?

Tags: php, html, jquery, jquery-validate

Estou fazendo o seguinte formulário para o cadastro de dados no banco, para inserir no banco estou utilizando `array` nos `input` `names` do formulário.

> [image: Formulário de cadastro]

```html
<form method="post" id="validar" action="?classe=Clientes&acao=create">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome_cliente">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_cliente" placeholder="Digite o Nome" name="clientes[nome_cliente]">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email_cliente">Email</label>
    <input type="email_cliente" class="form-control" id="email_cliente" placeholder="Digite o E-mail" name="clientes[email_cliente]">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="telefone_cliente">Telefone</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone_cliente" placeholder="Digite o Telefone" name="clientes[telefone_cliente]">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="senha_cliente">Senha</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha_cliente" placeholder="Digite a Senha" name="clientes[senha_cliente]">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="data_nasc_cliente">Data de Nascimento</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data_nasc_cliente" placeholder="Digite a Data de Nascimento" name="clientes[data_nasc_cliente]">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

e estou precisando fazer uma validação nos campos usando jquery validate, só que pra utilizar o jquery validate ele pega o name do input para validar.

```
<script>
    $("#validar").validate({
        rules:{
            clientes['nome_cliente']:{
                required:true
            }                             
        },
        messages:{
            clientes['nome_cliente']:{
                required:"Por favor, informe seu nome"
            }
        }    
    });
</script>
```

Tentei de várias formas, porém não consegui em nenhuma delas fazer a validação com o `array` no `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa colocar o nome entre aspas duplas no seu caso para que a validação ocorra por ser um tipo diferente do padrão, ***exemplo***:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
      "clientes[nome_cliente]": {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "clientes[nome_cliente]": {
        required: "Por favor, informe seu nome"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1" id="form1">
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="clientes[nome_cliente]" />
  <button>Verificar</button>
</form>
```

***Ref.*** [How to validate array of inputs using validate plugin jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-validate-plugin-jquery)

Comment: Muito obrigado, fiquei um bom tempo quebrando cabeça com isso, nem imaginei que era só colocar entre aspas.

Comment: Não esqueça de pontuar a resposta. e aceitar como resposta do sua pergunta @AndréPaiva