# Verificar se CPF já existe com Jquery Validate

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

Estou validando alguns campos de um formulário de uma aplicação que foi feita em Ruby on Rails. Nessa aplicação tem alguns endpoint de consulta, onde ele retorna um json, caso o CPF exista ele retorna esses dados:

```
{
  "existe": true,
  "user": {
  "name": "Operador 2",
  "cpf": "606.304.220-29"
  }
}
```

E caso não exista ele retorna

```
{  
   "existe":false
}
```

A URl para consultar o CPF fica da seguite forma: http://localhost:3000/api/findUserByCpf?cpf=606.304.220-28

E o código js do [Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), ele ta retornando a mensagem no console, mas **não tica o campo**, tornando o campo válido ou inválido.

```
$(".validationNomeOperador").validate({
rules: {
    'cpf': {
        required: true,
        cpf: true,
        remote: {
            url: "/api/findUserByCpf",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                cpf: function() {
                    return $("#validationCpfOperador").val()
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.existe == true) {
                    console.log("Já existe o CPF cadastrado")
                } else {
                    console.log("CPF disponivel")
                }
            }
        }
    },
},
messages: {
    'cpf': {
        required: "Informe o CPF",
        remote: 'CPF já cadastrado'
    },
}
});
```

Comment: as suas chaves estão muito estranhas ... o retorno true é daquele jeito mesmo?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic estava mesmo, acabei de editar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geralmente esse retorno é produzido como exemplo assim?

```
json_encode(array('existe' => 'true'));
```

para que o código do [jquery.validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) entenda na configuração de validação `remote` precisa ler essa chave da seguinte forma:

```
rules: {
    cpf: {
        required:true,
        remote: {
            url:'val.php',
            type:'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            dataFilter: function(d){
                response = JSON.parse(d);
                return !response.existe;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

fazendo essa configuração, o código busca se o resultado foi `true` ou `false` que é o que precisa para validar ou não o campo.

Comment: Muito obrigado com a sua resposta eu consegui fazer funcionar depois de alguns testes. Usando o exemplo que você postou, sempre ficava ou cpf válido ou cpf inválido, mesmo você digitando cpf já cadastrado, então observando a sua resposta e a do Victor, eu cheguei nesse código:

   dataFilter: function (d) {
                        response = JSON.parse(d);
                        return response.existe ? false : true;
                    }

Comment: Só alterar a linha return response.existe; para  return response.existe ? false : true;

Comment: @SérgioMachado é só colocar !. Vou alterar

Comment: Perfeito! já tava funcionando mas assim ficou melhor ainda

Comment: Teria como alterar o data? tipo na aplicação o name do campo é cliente[cpf] já no endepoint é apenas cpf

Comment: @SérgioMachado veja se é isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/374004/54880 qualquer coisa explica

Comment: não é isso, tive que usar essa técnica aí também, mas é o seguinte, no name do campo esta cliente[telefone] já na aplicação o endpoint foi configurado para apenas telefone, exemplo  /api/findClienteByTelefone?telefone=83999994444

Comment: @SérgioMachado eu não entendi muito bem a sua duvida, faz o seguinte abre outro questionamento explicando a nova duvida, aqui o pessoal gosta assim cada duvida para cada resposta ... tem como?

Comment: Eu vou fazer isso mesmo, pra não ficar bagunçado, até porque vai servir também para quando uma pessoa for buscar ajuda na internet

Comment: Criei outra pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376121/jquery-validate-renomeando-names-complexos-colchetes

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu acabei de ler na documentação, o seu parâmetro **remote** da requisição precisa manipular apenas `true` ou `false` para realizar a validação e exibir a mensagem customizada que você definiu no **JQuery Validate**.

Se a minha linha de raciocínio estiver correta, você deve alterar seu endpoint para retornar apenas `boolean` na **response** ou alterar a mensagem de validação dinamicamente com o próprio JQuery.

**Edit**

Mas pesquisando um pouco creio que achei uma solução para voçê; Troque o parâmetro `success` por `dataFilter`:

```
dataFilter: function(data) {        
    return data.existe ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Pois é, eu vi em vários sites a respeito disso também, mas eu imagino que da pra fazer algo, já que ele identifica quando o cliente é cadastrado ou não, retornar  true ou false. Eu imagino que para isso precise de um método customizado para a biblioteca

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta @SérgioMachado, vê se resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Não funcionou é muito estranho, mesmo identificando que o cpf é valido ou não, ele não ticava o campo, mas depois de ver a resposta do Virgilio, eu fiz alguns testes e funcionou, parece o que tava impedindo de funcionar corretamente era a falta do JSON.parse