# Jquery Validate renomeando names complexos (colchetes)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

Estou validando alguns campos de um formulário de uma aplicação que foi feita em Ruby on Rails. Nessa aplicação tem alguns endpoint de consulta, onde ele retorna um json, caso o CNPJ exista ele retorna esses dados:

```
{
   "existe": true,
   "loja": {
   "id": 16,
   "nome": "Loja Sergio"
   }
}
```

E caso não exista ele retorna

```
{  
  "existe":false
}
```

A URl para consultar o CNPJ fica da seguite forma: http://localhost:3000/api/findLojaByCnpj?cnpj=42.364.513/0001-21 via GET

Abaixo o trecho do código para tentar fazer a validação do campo usando a biblioteca [Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), usando o método **remote** da própria biblioteca, que acessa a URl e retorna true ou false.

```
$(".validateCadastrarLoja").validate({
 rules: {
    'loja[cnpj]': {
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: "/api/findLojaByCnpj",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                cnpj: function() {
                    return $("#validationCNPJ").val()
                }
            },
            dataFilter: function(d) {
                response = JSON.parse(d);
                return !response.existe;
            }
        }
    },
 },

 messages: {
    'loja[cnpj]': {
        required: "Informe o CNPJ.",
        cnpj: 'CNPJ inválido',
        remote: 'CNPJ já cadastrado'
    },
 }
});
```

Só que dessa forma ele ta fazendo uma requisição usando os dois parâmetros tanto o loja[cnpj] como o cnpj.

Gostaria que desse para **alterar o loja[cnpj] para o cnpj**, mas sem alterar a chamada no rules, busquei em muitos sites em inglês e não consegui encontrar nada

Comment: respondendo: se o seu campo é `loja[cnpj]` e por isso as regras são imposta nesse campo,  ou seja, esse é o nome do campo para validar, só consegue tal coisa se mudar o nome do campo html para `cnpj` ... não vejo problema ele passar dois parâmetros.

Comment: você acha que não tem problema? vou fazer uns testes aqui

Comment: Não tem problema não é só um parâmetro a mais você pode resgatar o próprio parâmetro ... também é uma alternativa.